# GNU Screen terminal line settings

Tags: gnu-screen, stty

I want to use GNU screen to monitor to a serial USB port like this:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

But I need to tweak a few terminal line settings. I have made several attempts but none seem to work. For example, to send NL+CR for a newline character, not just NL, the terminal line setting is onlcr.

**Attempt 1** - without any special settings:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
# only sends NL
```

**Attempt 2** - via screen:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200,onlcr
# still only sends NL
```

**Attempt 3** - via ssty:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 onlcr
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
# still only sends NL
```

**Attempt 4** - via both:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 onlcr
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200,onlcr
# still only sends NL
```

**Attempt 5** - in the other order:

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200,onlcr
# then ctrl+a, ctrl+z to pause the screen session
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 onlcr
stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: Device or resource busy
```

In all cases, if I run stty to check the terminal line settings I get this:

**Before running screen** - note the -onlcr is present:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
```

**Changing the stty setting** - note the -onlcr has gone:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 onlcr
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost 
-isig -icanon -echo
```

**After running screen** - note the -onlcr is back again:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
```

It's as if screen ignores any stty settings and resets them to it's own defaults. And this the same on both machines I tested it on; Debain 8.7 and macOS Sierra 10.12.4

I have seen posts with other people facing similar problems but none give a definitive answer. Many people end up recommending an alternative to screen like minicom but now I'm interested.

Can stty settings, like onlcr, be used with screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through much the same process, only to find out the screen clobbers the stty settings no matter what.  One comment here suggests changing the screen source code:
[How to toggle CR/LF in gnu screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812142/how-to-toggle-cr-lf-in-gnu-screen)

In the end, I was very happy to find a more minimal dumb-terminal program that allows passing stty-style arguments on the command line:
https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom

It also pretty-prints the serial port settings when it starts so you can easily check them.

Packages exist in Debian-derived distros (`sudo apt-get install picocom`), and for others it seems that compilation is straightforward.  One dependency is the linenoise library, which can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this is to start `screen` running without any special terminal options using in your case: `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`, and then leave it running, and switch over to another terminal window and do the `stty` commands from there.

If you stop `screen`, I think it locks the device somehow (or else its because you aren't using `sudo`). Once in the other window you can type the `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 onlcr` and that will change the behavior of the `screen` session from then on. The problem is that `screen` is ignoring the setting passed to it and just configuring the tty its own way. You can type `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a` to list the settings from another window while screen is running and then alter them as needed. (Note that on the Mac, the `-F` should be lower case.)

If you only have the one terminal window then it is problematic because putting `screen` in the background and leaving it running just mixes input and output streams between the shell and `screen` process.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do if you have two terminal windows open is a low-level fallback hack when nothing is working: In one terminal type `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`. Then in the other set up the terminal options you want with `sudo stty`. Then from this same terminal you can send commands via `echo "Some text" > /dev/ttyUSB0`. You can translate the output of the cat command by piping it through `sed` or `tr`. For example `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tr '\r' '\n'` will translate any received carriage returns to line feeds.